# Determine whether two Git branches have diverged

Tags: git, branch

I'd like to determine whether two Git branches have diverged or whether one of the branches could simply be fast forwarded to the other branch.

In other words, I want to check whether the current HEAD of one of the branches has been merged into the other branch at some point or if it contains commits that are not in the other branch.

Is there a way to do this without actually merging the two branches? A simple `git diff` does not help in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using this shell script snippet for that purpose:

```
git_is_merged () {
    local revlist
    if revlist=$(git rev-list -1 "$1" --not "$2"); then
        if [ "$revlist" = "" ]; then
            echo "'$1' IS merged into '$2'."
        else
            echo "'$1' is NOT merged into '$2'."
        fi
    fi
}

alias gim='git_is_merged'
```

Use it like `gim origin/devel origin/master` to determine whether `origin/devel` is merged into `origin/master`.

**Edit:** For the sake of completeness, if you are working with named branches only, you could also use

```
git branch --contains origin/devel | grep -q origin/master && echo "Merged" || echo "Not merged"
```

or

```
git branch --merged origin/master | grep -q origin/devel && echo "Merged" || echo "Not merged"
```

for the same purpose.

Comment: Very nice :) I was playing around with `git for-each-ref | grep $(git merge-base <branch1> <branch2>)`, and thought about writing a shell function, but your solution definitely seems cleaner.

Comment: @sschuberth apologies didn't mean to step on your toes there with the suggested edit. There is just no need to make an alias when you already have a function. Not using the local keyword within the function means the revlist var persists in the environment after it executes. & not quoting the arguments $1/$2 can lead to trouble with strange branch names that are still valid and allowed by git; including semi-colons, quotes and such. The edit was approved by two reviewers without further changes I imagine for these reasons.

Comment: @ReenignE No worries. I'm grateful for edits that bring clear value, but in this case the value was not clear to me (and this time it's me who does not want to step on your toes). Maybe that's just due to my intermediate knowledge of Bash. I deliberately used this "superfluous" alias to emphasize what `gim` stands for. But I see the value of quoting arguments and having a local variable now, and have adjusted my answer accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: @sschuberth I suppose my reasoning is that people who learn from code like this may not realize a function may be invoked directly. I agree that simply naming the function gim isn't as readable. Do you think a comment above with descriptive text on the functions purpose would be a better approach?

Comment: @sschuberth Thanks for taking those points into consideration! I do want to point out pitfalls #25 and #27 from this link which are relevant here. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#function_foo.28.29 The return value $? is now masked by the local var declaration and will likely always return 0, this being why in the edit it was separate from where the var was being set.

Comment: @ReenignE Unfortunately I get "502 Bad Gateway" for your link.

Comment: @sschuberth Ah sorry it does for you? Still seems to be working for me. Does an archive.org link of it work for you? https://web-beta.archive.org/web/20170115010427/http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#function_foo.28.29

Comment: @ReenignE Thanks, I've applied the changes.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `git merge-base`

A description can be found [here](http://man.he.net/man1/git-merge-base).

Comment: And to complete it: `m="$(git merge-base b1 b2)"; test "$m" = "$(git rev-parse b1)" -o "$m" = "$(git rev-parse b2)";`

Comment: Also try, `git merge-base --is-ancestor origin/main main; echo $?` to see if origin/main is ancestor of main or not (ie if main has diverged or not)

Answer (score 4):

If it can simply be fast-forwarded, `git merge --ff-only otherbranch` will succeed. (And if it can't, it will be rejected rather than a merge commit being made.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a graphical tool, you can use `gitk branch1 branch2`.
This also allows you to inspect the diverging commits, if needed.